# How to center a div in html & css, always keep the aspect ratio, and fill max screen width/height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't seem to realise the following setup with html and css. I need 3 divs:

- header (fixed height)
- footer (fixed height)
- content (fixed aspect ratio, has to be centered and has to be "as big as possible")

I have a spread of a book (an image) and I want it to be as big as possible. I'm planning on placing as a background image of the content div.

I made this mockup to make things clear:

[image]

Anyone got any idea's how I can realise this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is almost what I'm looking for!! The only thing I want to add, is the aspect ratio of the image. The width and the height of the image always have to be in the same ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of the page using jquery

```
$(function()
  {
  $('.fullLength') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) -72)});
    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
    $('.fullLength') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) -72)});

  });        
});
```

For the width just set it at a percentage and then use css with margin: 0 auto

I have added a fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/G3G4x/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [supersized plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/).

And this is [link](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) how to keep footer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My footer is now at the bottom of my page. However I can't seem to realise the content div at the center of the page at maximum width & height.

Comment: Supersized plugin will center image and keep ratio for you.

Comment: [link](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/core/3.2/core.html) is example for simple background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML and CSS only like in the jsfiddle i made : http://jsfiddle.net/QBB4j/

HTML :

```
<header>
    Header, fixed height
</header>

<div id=main>
    <div id=book>
        <img src="myimage.png" />
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
   Footer, fixed height
</footer>
```

Css :

```
header {
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#book img {
    width: 80%;
    height:80%;
    margin: auto;
}
footer {
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

In this example the aspect ratio isn't kept, as the width and height will always be 80%. The aspect ratio needs to be fixed.

Comment: oh, i coded it for a square picture, just modify the height/width percent as you need